# How to access element present on stack using bp, after creating a local variable?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I am using NASM 8086.
How can I access 3rd and 4th element present on stack using bp?
Here is my code

```
mov ax, 1
push ax  ; 1st element on stack
mov ax, 2; 2nd element on stack
push ax

push bp ; save old value of bp
mov bp, sp ; make bp our reference point
sub sp, 2 ; creates a local variable,it can be accessed by [bp-2]

mov bx,3
push bx ; 3rd element on stack
mov cx,4
push cx ; 4th element on stack

mov bx, [bp+6] ; load 1st element in bx
mov cx, [bp+4] ; load 2nd element in cx
mov ax, [bp-2] ; load local variable in ax
```

Now how to write bp to access 3rd and 4th element on stack

Comment: watch your `mov cs, 4` when you obviously mean `mov cx, 4`. changing your code segment midstream cannot be good.

Comment: You do not have to do **move reg, val** and then **push reg** - you can **push val** directly

Comment: @Artur: `push val` with an immediate value [was introduced with the 186](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insPUSH). When programming strictly for the 8086 then it is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're calling the 3rd element would be at `[bp-4]`, and the "fourth" would be `[bp-6]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your routine to get 4 arguments push them on stack before:

```
push bp ; save old value of bp
mov bp, sp ; make bp our reference point
sub sp, 2 ; creates a local variable,it can be accessed by [bp-2]
```

In addition you must terminate your function with:

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

That code:

```
mov bx,3
push bx ; 3rd element on stack
mov cs,4
push cx ; 4th element on stack
```

looks like you are trying to prepare args for new function call.

This should be slightly different:

To match **cdecl** (this exampe uses cdecl) calling convention (you need that if you want to use your asm with c etc) you must push input args in reverse order - say you want 4 input args (ints - 32bit). Asm transcript of C/C++ call func(0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd) looks like that:

```
push 0DDh   4bytes
push 0CCh
push 0BBh
push 0AAh
call func   // another 'push'
add esp, 10h
```

Now your routine may look like this:

```
push ebp    //next push
mov ebp, esp

// your args are '2 pushes' away (call, push ebp) = 8 bytes away
// hence 1st arg is [ebp+8], 2nd is [ebp+12], 3rd is [ebp+16], 4th is [ebp+20]
// loading args to regs

mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]   // 0xAA - 1st arg
mov ebx, dword ptr [ebp+12]  // 0xBB - 2nd arg
mov ecx, dword ptr [ebp+16]  // 0xCC - 3rd arg
mov edx, dword ptr [ebp+20]  // 0xDD - 4th arg

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

but if you want to use local variables - here is how to use 2 local variables along with 4 int variables passed as arguments:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, 8  // for 2 local int(32bit) variables

mov dword ptr[ebp-4], 3   // set one local var to 3
mov dword ptr[ebp-8], 4   // set one local var to 4

mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]   // 0xAA - 1st arg
mov ebx, dword ptr [ebp+12]  // 0xBB - 2nd arg
mov ecx, dword ptr [ebp+16]  // 0xCC - 3rd arg
mov edx, dword ptr [ebp+20]  // 0xDD - 4th arg

add esp, 8 // remove space for local vars

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```